# Running docker stack deploy just hangs

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run my `docker-compose` setup into my localhost kubernetes cluster that comes default with Docker for Desktop.

I run the following command and it just .. hangs???

```
> docker stack deploy --orchestrator=kubernetes -c docker-compose.yml hornet

Ignoring unsupported options: build

Ignoring deprecated options:

container_name: Setting the container name is not supported.

expose: Exposing ports is unnecessary - services on the same network can access each other's containers on any port.

top-level network "backend" is ignored
top-level network "frontend" is ignored
service "website.public": network "frontend" is ignored
service "website.public": container_name is deprecated
service "website.public": build is ignored
service "website.public": depends_on are ignored
....
<snip> heaps of services 'ignored'
....

Waiting for the stack to be stable and running...
```

The `docker-compose up` command works great, locally, when I run that.

Is there any ways I can try and see what's going on under the hood, which hangs this?

Comment: It seems (from attached logs) like you are trying to create networks into docker-compose file which is pretty unusual while working in k8s environment.

Comment: the networks were created to simulate how the microservices where split up. It was only _afterwards_ that I moved from docker-compose to K8 that I realised that this was ignored. So I didn't create my docker-compose (initially) for a K8 scenario, but trying to leverage that now, in k8's and seeing what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I am afraid that you can use docker-compose directly in k8s cluster. either you can create deployment and service file. In case you are looking for fun try using https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose

Comment: AH - so i'll need two docker-compose files then? Also, Kompose doesn't work for me because it the _current_ release doesnt support version 3.5

Comment: kubernetes deployment file is different from docker-compose. you can't directly deploy docker-compose to k8s.

Comment: @PrateekJain "I am afraid that you can use docker-compose directly in k8s cluster.". I _think_ you ment "can NOT use" ? So .. if we cannot use docker-compose, then why does docker offer `docker stack deploy --orchestrator=kubernetes ...` ?

Comment: I haven't deployed apps using this command as in my opinion most of the people trying/using k8s are using kubectl or helm to deploy apps in cluster.  Also, you might want to check your docker version and version of compose file. I would recommend you to first try simple examples as shown here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/